# How to set up CodeIgniter site on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, localhost

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to set up a CodeIgniter site on my local host. The site is working fine online. Here are the steps I have undertaken to migrate the site to my local host.

1. edited the base_url in the application/config/congfig.php

   ```
   $config['base_url']      = "http://localhost/MyProjects/Project/reservation/";
   ```
2. changed the database connect settings in the application/config/database.php to connect to localhost database
3. have set up the database

The working site URL looks like this: www.example.com/reservation/index.php

I have placed the site files in MyProjects/Project directory in local server.
I am trying to access

```
'http://localhost/MyProjects/Project/reservation/index.php'
```

But it returns the blank page. (Empty body element: )

here are the contents of the application\config\routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";  

require_once BASEPATH.'database/DB'.EXT;

$db_obj = DB(); 
$new_branches = $db_obj->get('table_branches');
$new_branches = $new_branches->result();


foreach($new_branches as $branch){
   $route[trim($branch->url)]   = "reserve/index/".$branch->url;
   $route[trim($branch->url).'/']   = "reserve/index/".$branch->url;
   $route[trim($branch->url).'/admin']  = "admin";

}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is that exactly what your `routes.php` file contains?

Comment: yes. in application/config/routes.php

Comment: If you get a blank page then you should turn on errors. Put this at the top of your `index.php` file: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: added these lines. But still getting blank page. nothing is there in the body of the page. <body></body>

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your route file at line 3 :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";  
==> employee_punchin|admin)\S*'] = "reserve/routing/$1";
```

should fix it:

```
$route['(employee_punchin|admin)\S*'] = "reserve/routing/$1";
```

in your index.php file, change the ENVIRONMENT to development to display errors :

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Comment: sorry 3rd line was commented in the file. Forgot to remove it while pasting it.

Comment: no. I am not getting any errors. I'm not sure why it is not working. Fortunately I have previous backup version of production site. I am able set it up on my local system. I'll compare the two, if I find the solution I will post it here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you post your project architecture here !